# Can LinkedHashMap (or something like it) use a custom ordering?

Tags: java, caching

And by this question, I mean: I have a Java cache implementation that is using [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to implement the cache.  However, I have come to realize that I need an ordering besides Least Recently Used or Last Inserted when maintaining my cache.  But I really like the other features of `LinkedHashMap` for implementing a cache, such as a size-limited map and the customizable [`removeEldestEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)) method.  Since this is a cache of potentially tens of thousands of objects, I'm not sure the [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is fast enough to build off of (but I have not tested this yet).

My final constraint is: keep in mind this is in an existing code base of hundreds of thousands of lines of code that is very far along the development cycle.  Because of this, we can't just swap new COTS/OTS in as needed because of the considerable regression testing and rework required.  We are currently using Java 7, [Guava Release 09](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html) (Ouch! I know...) and [Apache Commons Collections 3.2.1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/index.html)

Comment: No, there's not really a way to do that.  What ordering do you actually want?

Comment: Suffice it to say it's a custom ordering based on the key being used, and something that takes a `Comparator<? super K>` would work nicely.  TreeMap would probably be a good fit except for wanting an easy way to bound the size, and performance.

Comment: If you want to order based on a comparator, there's provably nothing that'll do asymptotically better than a `TreeMap`.  Proof: if you insert n entries, they have to be sorted at the end; there are n! ways n entries could be sorted, so to distinguish between the possible sortings takes log(n!) comparisons, log(n!) is asymptotically n log n, so you need at least O(log n) comparisions per entry.  If you want to bound the size, you can write a small wrapper around `TreeMap` to do that (possibly with Guava's `ForwardingMap`.)

Comment: When you say that you need to customise the ordering do you mean that you want to be able to control which entry is sent as `eldest` to `removeEldestEntry`? For example to lock some items into the cache?

Comment: @sprinter -That is pretty much exactly what we need to do.  Not necessarily the locking part (more like "importance" than locking), but being able to control what `removeEldestEntry` considers for removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this. If you look at the source code of `LinkedHashMap` you'll see that the mechanism is very simple: any time an item is accessed it is moved to the end of a (private) linked list. The item at the head is then the least recently accessed. It is efficient but not particularly sophisticated.

One option is to extend the class to override the mechanism for selecting the item to remove. You could do this by overriding `addEntry` to do something more sophisticated such as remove one or more items that you know will not be accessed again.

Something like this might be possible:

```
class MyHashMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> {
    LinkedList<String> lowPriorityItems = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    void addEntry(int hash, String key, String value, int bucketIndex) {
        if (isLowValue(key)) {
            lowPriorityItems.add(key);
        }
        if (size >= threshold) {
            if (lowPriorityItems.isEmpty()) {
                super.addEntry(hash, key, value, bucketIndex);
            else {
                removeAll(lowPriorityItems);
                lowPriorityItems.clear();
                super.createEntry(hash, key, value, bucketIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's just an example but it would basically work by periodically removing items in the cache as you get close to the threshold. If there are no low priority items in the cache then it falls back to using the default method.

Hopefully you can see how you could make this more sophisticated to suit your needs.

Comment: Nice idea!  I am already subclassing LinkedHashMap to provide my own removeEldestEntry method, so this is not much of a tweak beyond that.  I'll give this a shot!